# Trouble with Tab Layout in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I use android.support:design library for NavigationDrawer and Tabs.
I have a trouble in fragment with tabs, it's shadow beetwen Toolbar and Tabs.
[Tabs fragment screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBrSj.png)

MainActivity layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/coordinate"
tools:context="tabs.com.tabs.com.fragments.items">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment tabs layout:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="tabs.com.tabs.com.fragments.items"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:duplicateParentState="true">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="6dp">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tabs code:

```
public class Items extends Fragment {


public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 2;




public Items() {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news,null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);



    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));



    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });


    return x;
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return new PrimaryFragment();
            case 1 : return new SocialFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "ONE";
            case 1 :
                return "TWO";

        }
        return null;
    }


}
}
```

How i can solve this trouble?

Comment: `AppBarOverlay` adds the shadow on your toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting same value for Elevation to both the TabLayout and ActionBar, as the ToolBar is 6dp elevated so it is casting its shadow over Tabs.
Set `android:elevation="6dp"` to ToolBar as it is in TabLayout.

For those who are using AppCompatActivity it is easy too, just set elevation like,

getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

**=============================Update================================**

***1)***
Another approach is that u make a layout having shadow part inside drawable and use it below your Tabs in XML designing.

In `res/drawable/shadow.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="#33000000"
    android:angle="90">
</gradient>
```

Now use it as

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/TabLayoutID"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow" />
```

In your main XML containing TabLayout.

***2)***

Or just Add this line in your style(s): if above way doesn't work.

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/shadow</item>
```

Hope, i have helped..!

Comment: I add same elevation to Toolbar and Tabs, but shadow still here.

Comment: set elevation to 0 for both..!

Comment: When a set elevation:0, it's hides shadow beetween and below tabs, but i need shadow below tabs. I try set elevation only tabs, but don't work.

Comment: Glad i was helpful.! :) happy coding.!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the shadow of `toolbar` add this to your app theme:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

And You use `design-support library` so you have to also add below line code.

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```